# Swift subclassing UITextField issues

Tags: uitextfield, swift, uitextfielddelegate, xcode6

I've subclassed UITextField and added two variables and a convenience function. One variables holds a String key and the other holds a reference to another TextField which is used to create a custom tab order.

All good except I've run into a small problem. Using the storyboard I'm not able to bind the IBOutlet in the controller to the text field elements that implement this subclass even though they are both the same type. I've had to set the IBOutlet variable to be a UITextField type, bind them and then set the IBOutlet back to the subclass.

This all works in Xcode5 using Objective-C so I assume this is an issue with the beta of XCode6 but just wanted confirm I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beta 2 Release of XCode 6 has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am also playing with swift.. I can share what I checked when faced some problems, you can check these. Not sure though it is the solution for your problem.
1. Check class defined for subclass and main class
2. Check delegates defined for text fields.
3. Check if prototyping can solve your problem.